# Как в Twig вывести нужное количество циклов

Tags: twig

```
{% for category in categories %}
   <li><a href="{{ category.href }}">{{ category.name}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Требуется вывести только первых три значения из указанного массива

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, проще пареной репы:

```
{% for category in categories|slice(0,7) %}
   <li><a href="{{ category.href }}">{{ category.name}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```